# select a column having particular year

Tags: pandas, date, dataframe

```
year     Odisha
2011-12  2265
2012-13  112
2012-13  156
2014-15  172
2011-12  197
```

select year 2012-13 and year 2014-15 from data frame

```
year_df=new_df[(new_df['Duration']=='2013-14' & 
                new_df['Duration']=='2014-15')]
```

I got error-:

> cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `&` to `|` and add `)` and `(`:

```
year_df=new_df[(new_df['Duration']=='2013-14') | (new_df['Duration']=='2014-15')]
```

What is same using [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
year_df=new_df[new_df['Duration'].isin(['2013-14', '2014-15'])]
```